# Angular 2 how to style transcluded elements?

Tags: angular

```
<component>
  <p class="component-p"></p>
</component>
```

`component` stylesheet:

```
.component-p {
  color: red;
}

:host .component-p {
  color: red;
}

:host >>> .component-p {
  color: red;
}

>>> .component-p {
  color: red;
}

::content .component-p {
  color: red;
}
```

None of these seem to work, but I don't understand why.

If I put `::content .component-p` in the parent component of this then it works, but that doesn't make any sense since I'm not transcluding it into the parent, but rather the child which is `component`.

How do you style transcluded content?

Comment: please post proper code and tell us where you use `:host {}` style. In parent or child?

Comment: @micronyks I've posted everything that there is. The stylesheet belongs to `component`, it's just simple things that I've tried. The part about parent and child was just an example, here there is no parent. Only `component`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `:host /deep/ .component-p` when using angular-cli.

https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/angular-advanced-styling-guide-v4-f0765616e635

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE** : There are many ways to do it. But here I'm using you how to style `ng-content element/control` from **child component**.

use `:host >>> .component-p` to select  transcluded element as shown here.

```
 styles: [`
                :host >>> .component-p {color:red;}
        `]
```

This works as expected.

**DEMO : https://plnkr.co/edit/z3urbPNvDXEnJZDMZo74?p=preview**

Comment: That's way I asked for your code. Because you can do it from child or parent.

Comment: play with plunker and tell me your problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what to add or edit, because I'm doing the exact same thing as in your example.

Comment: @micronyks this doesn't work when using angular-cli. Checkout my answer.

Comment: @DavidGonzalezShannon not sure with Angular-cli as I don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

The styles for the transcluded elements should be in the component where your `<component>` is used. For example, let's say we have this component:

```
@Component({
      selector: 'app-other',
      template: `
          <p>something here</p>
          <ng-content></ng-content>
       `,
}) export class OtherComponent {}
```

If we use this in our `app.component`, the styles for code that goes inside `ng-content` must be written here.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: `
         <app-other>
             <p class="component-p">some things</p>
         </app-other>
    `,
    styles: [`
        .component-p {
            color: red;
         }
    `]
 }) export class AppComponent {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular generates some markup in the shadow DOM that prevents us from styling due to wrong selection. Best way I found that allows you to select by specificity is by turning off this autogenerated markup in the component decorator, like so:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ss-primary-button',
  templateUrl: './primary-button.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./primary-button.component.less'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native
})
```

You are after **encapsulation** here. The above value forces 'normal browser behaviour'. ViewEncapsulation is imported from angular core, like so:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
```

Now you should be able to select your markup, including transcluded content, as per normal CSS, LESS or SASS.